# Prevent Azure from swapping VMSS release while VM is still booting up

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nginx, php

I use Azure DevOps to release a new VM into a VMSS.

When I release the update, Azure swaps the images while the `PHP-FPM` process is still booting up. This results in `502 Bad Gateway` errors for approximately 30 seconds. The PHP-FPM boot process takes roughly a minute to complete.

What I think is happening is that Azure identifies that Nginx is responding and assumes that the VM is fully booted; however, NGINX throws 502 errors because PHP-FPM hasn't completed it's boot process, and it cannot yet find the PHP-FPM socket.

Azure CLI command that is used to release the image: `az vmss update`

Is there a method to either:

1. Add a timeout delay before azure swaps the VM?
2. Check to see if NGINX is throwing a 502 error and delay until it isn't?